# Черный фон при ресайзе изображения

Tags: gd, изображения, php

Здравствуйте, есть функция предназначенная для ресайза изображения.
Но, после ресайза вместо прозрачного фона у первого изображения, у второго появляется черный фон.

Функция:

```
function resize($file_input, $file_output, $w_o, $h_o, $percent = false) {  
    list($w_i, $h_i, $type) = getimagesize($file_input);  
    if (!$w_i || !$h_i) {  
        echo 'Невозможно получить длину и ширину изображения';  
        return;  
        }  
        $types = array('','gif','jpeg','png');  
        $ext = $types[$type];  
        if ($ext) {  
                $func = 'imagecreatefrom'.$ext;  
                $img = $func($file_input);  
        } else {  
                echo 'Некорректный формат файла';  
        return;  
        }
    if ($percent) {  
        $w_o *= $w_i / 100;  
        $h_o *= $h_i / 100;  
    }  
    if (!$h_o) $h_o = $w_o/($w_i/$h_i);  
    if (!$w_o) $w_o = $h_o/($h_i/$w_i);

    $img_o = imagecreatetruecolor($w_o, $h_o);  
    imagecopyresampled($img_o, $img, 0, 0, 0, 0, $w_o, $h_o, $w_i, $h_i);  
    if ($type == 2) {  
        return imagepng($img_o,$file_output,100);  
    } else {  
        $func = 'image'.$ext;  
        return $func($img_o,$file_output);  
    }  
}
```

Функция взята [отсюда](http://recens.ru/php/resize_and_crop.html) 
Функция вызывается:

```
resize('crop.jpg', 'avatar.jpg', 100, 0);
```

Comment: Обсуждался кажись тут этот вопрос http://hashcode.ru/questions/172719/php-%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B7%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D1%84%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D0%B2-gd